# On tiktok API I am getting continuously error of redirect_uri

Tags: php, api, rest, tiktok

On Tiktok dashboard i use redirect domain as natya.soundgallery.pk

and below is my code for index.php that is uploaded on natya.soundgallery.pk

```
<?php
// Set your app id and secret key here
$appId = '<app-id>';
$secretKey = '<secret-key>';

// Set your redirect URL
$redirectUrl = 'https://natya.soundgallery.pk/index.php';

// Set the scope required for analytics
$scope = 'user.stats';

// Generate the authorization URL
$authorizationUrl = 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/platform/oauth/connect?' . http_build_query([
    'client_key' => $appId,
    'response_type' => 'code',
    'scope' => $scope,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectUrl,
]);

// Redirect the user to the authorization URL
header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
?>
```

I have tried

```
$redirectUrl = 'https://natya.soundgallery.pk/';
$redirectUrl = 'natya.soundgallery.pk';
$redirectUrl = 'https://www.natya.soundgallery.pk/index.php';
```

but always i got the same following error

If you're a developer, correct the following and try again:
redirect_uri